# MySQL Performance for Online Games Highscore Lists

Tags: php, mysql, database, online-game

I have a question about making "Highscore-Lists".

Lets say I have an online game with 1.000.000 active users. Each user has points from 0 to X. Now, I want to show a ranking-list. It would be insane to show all million entries in one page so it is divided into Y pages (100 entries each page => 10.000 pages).

I am not really sure how to solve it.

### 1. The easiest way to do that would be loading all 1m entries

in one SELECT, get the result and find current user with a for loop and show that specific page. (but all other 999.900 entries will be saved in RAM eventhough its not showing up). For a page change I could just use the result data with no second database call. (So I don't care about point changes during that time)

```
SELECT UserName, UserID, Points FROM UserAccount ORDER BY Points;
```

### 2. My second idea was, to load each page individually but than I do not know

2.1 if it is really better performance
2.2 how to get the right start page because I only have the points of the user but not really his place

So how could I solve that problem. I dont really know what mysql can handle. Are more small calls better then one huge call.
Can I even save huge result data?
Second solution would update all changed points with each page change, though but i care more about performance then always uptodate list-data.

Thank you for your help!
Markus

Comment: This is a simple question about pagination. There are thousands of solutions out there - selecting just what's needed, selecting everything to json/xml, infinite scroll, hybrid solutions, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was already searching for something like this but could not find the right tutorial. I have a usertable with points. When I select all with orderBy points i have place 1 to 1m automatically. But If I solve it with paging how can I find the offset I need because I would need the position from the general selection (let it be position 5530) and then build my offset out of it (5530/100 items each page = Page 55 => 55 * 100 = 5500, So Offset 5500 Limit 100.) But how do I get the position i need?

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination. In SQL it's a "limit" clause:

```
SELECT UserName, UserID, Points FROM UserAccount ORDER BY Points LIMIT 0, 20;
```

The above query will return only the first 20 rows of the original selection.

You can pass page parameters via get, like this: highscore.php?page=1 or ?page=2 and so on.